# Why does converting a SDL Surface work when the surface was loaded from a file but not when it was generated from a font file

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

On my 2nd project I work with opengl and SDL2. I want to render the text to a surface with SDL2 and then convert it.

I am already loading textures from files with SDL so I have a function that can convert Surfaces. Still when I supply a surface generated by the TTF_Render function the result is this:
[image]

Now I dont know why this is happening so some support would be appreciated.

I am using the SDL_ttf libary to load the file. 
I am using visual studio 2015 as the ide.

Here is my convert function:

```
GLuint JUMA_Texture::loadFromSurface(SDL_Surface *img, GLenum target, GLenum filtering) {
    GLuint TextureID = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &TextureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureID);
    std::cout << " got " << img;
    if (target == GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    {
        glTexParameteri(target, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(target, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   // Set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    }
    int Mode = GL_RGB;
    if (img->format->BytesPerPixel == 4) {
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        transparent = true;
        Mode = GL_RGBA;
    }

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, Mode, img->w, img->h, 0, Mode, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img->pixels);
    glGenerateMipmap(target);
    return TextureID;
}
```

I printed the address of the surface pointers before and after it has been send to the function and they seem identical.

Also I am writing the surface to a file using SDL_SaveBmp and it seems fine aswell.

Edit:

Due to request I will now post the code for the use functions as well as the constructors of my shader and texture classes.

**Shader constructor/loader**

```
printf("Loading shader");
    // 1. Retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath
    std::string vertexCode;
    std::string fragmentCode;
    std::ifstream vShaderFile;
    std::ifstream fShaderFile;
    strcpy_s(Fragpath, fragmentPath);
    strcpy_s(Vertexpath, vertexPath);

    printf(".");
    // ensures ifstream objects can throw exceptions:
    vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);
    fShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);
    try
    {
        // Open files
        vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
        fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
        std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
        // Read file's buffer contents into streams
        vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
        fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();
        // close file handlers
        vShaderFile.close();
        fShaderFile.close();
        // Convert stream into string
        vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
        fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
        printf(".");
    }
    catch (std::ifstream::failure e)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
    }
    const GLchar* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
    const GLchar * fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();
    // 2. Compile shaders
    GLuint vertex, fragment;
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    // Vertex Shader
    vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex);
    // Print compile errors if any
    glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    printf(".");
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // Fragment Shader
    fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment);
    // Print compile errors if any
    glGetShaderiv(fragment, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    printf(".");
    // Shader Program
    this->Program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(this->Program, vertex);
    glAttachShader(this->Program, fragment);
    glLinkProgram(this->Program);
    // Print linking errors if any
    glGetProgramiv(this->Program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(this->Program, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    printf(".");
    // Delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessery
    glDeleteShader(vertex);
    glDeleteShader(fragment);
    printf("done\n");
```

**Shader use function**

```
void JUMA_Shader::Use()
{
    glUseProgram(this->Program);
}
```

**Texture constructor**

```
printf("loading Texture");
    int pos;
    pos = filePath.find(".");
    if (filePath.substr(pos) == ".png") {

        IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    }
    else if (filePath.substr(pos) == ".jpg")
        IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_JPG);

    SDL_Surface *img = IMG_Load(filePath.c_str());
    id = loadFromSurface(img,target,filtering);
```

**Texture::loadFromSurface** (NOTE: I HAVE NOT YET IMPLEMENTED CHECKING FOR GL_BGR AND GL_BGRA HOWEVER I HAVE MANUALLY ATTEMPTED BOTH OF THESE MODES WITH NO DIFFERENT EFFECT AT THIS MOMENT.)

```
GLuint JUMA_Texture::loadFromSurface(SDL_Surface *img, GLenum target, GLenum filtering) {
    GLuint TextureID = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &TextureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureID);
    std::cout << " got " << img;
    if (target == GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    {
        glTexParameteri(target, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(target, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   // Set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    }
    int Mode = GL_RGB;
    if (img->format->BytesPerPixel == 4) {
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        transparent = true;
        Mode = GL_RGBA;
    }

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, Mode, img->w, img->h, 0, Mode, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img->pixels);
    glGenerateMipmap(target);
    return TextureID;
}
```

**Texture::USE**

```
int JUMA_Texture::use(GLenum Channel) {
    glActiveTexture(Channel);   // Activate the texture unit first before binding texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

    if (transparent)
    {
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    }
    return 1;
}
```

Also here is what I am seeing right now (Note that I have checked again and this is not the color I set for my font as I previously stated. I dont know where this blue color is coming from. I am currently trying to figure this out)
[image]

Lastly here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 texcoords;
out vec2 texCoords;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
out vec4 pos;
void main()
{
    pos=gl_Position = projection*view*model*vec4(position,1.0f);
    texCoords=vec2(texcoords.xy);
};
```

And my fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 color;
in vec2 texCoords;
in vec4 pos;
uniform sampler2D ourTexture;
uniform vec4 mixCol;

void main()
{
    vec4 texColor = texture(ourTexture, texCoords);
    if(texColor.a < 0.1f)
         discard;

    color = texColor;
};
```

**My font constructor**

```
    JUMA_Font::JUMA_Font(char *path, int size, SDL_Color color, char* text, char *uniform) {
    TTF_Init();
    font = TTF_OpenFont(path, 40);
    sourceSurface = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, text, color);
    printf("%d %d %d %d", color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a);
};
```

**convert font to texture**

```
JUMA_Texture convertToTexture() {
        JUMA_Texture _this;
        SDL_SaveBMP(sourceSurface, "out.bmp"); //outputs font correctly
        std::cout << "Expected " << sourceSurface;
        _this.id = _this.loadFromSurface(sourceSurface,GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_NEAREST);

        return _this;
    }
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The code you added is loading the texture from a file (Texture constructor), which you stated works fine. Is that still the case? I.e. when you load an image from file and send the surface to `loadFromSurface()`, does everything work correctly? In that case, the interesting part of the code is the creation of the surface from a font (`TTF_Render*`), which is still missing.

Comment: Alright I am adding the complete Font class... Please hold

Comment: @Meyer I have added everything you wanted. Also the images are still loaded correctly

Comment: @Meyer also I might have to add that transparency does not work even when loading images.

Comment: @Meyer After messing around a bit I found out that changing the 2nd mode in 

` glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, Mode, img->w, img->h, 0, Mode, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img->pixels);` 

to GL_BGRA makes the color of the rect change from blue to the color I selected for the font.

Comment: *I might have to add that transparency does not work even when loading images.* Oh, so the font problem most likely is solved with `TTF_Render*_Blended()`, but there is a bigger underlying problem. In that case I can only recommend to start from scratch and create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and open a new question that specifically deals with the missing transparency,
to get more people to have a look at it.

Comment: In general, make sure that the used window (SDL/Glut/...) is initialized with alpha support. Enable blending at the start of the program (`glEnable(GL_BLEND)`...). Use `color = vec4(texColor.aaa, 1.0);` (.rrr, .ggg, .bbb) in the fragment shader to inspect the individual channels and see if the alpha chanel has any information in it.

Comment: Please excuse my stupidity. I was working on a small game previously and wanted to start a new one. In the small game I used a different fragment shader than usual and I accidentally copied it over without checking. It was a different one than I supplied in my post without proper support for alpha shading. After changing back to my default shader (the one I posted) it worked. I have awarded my check to the answer that pretty much fixed almost everything by the glorious @Meyer. Thanks to you my issue was pretty much solved instantly and it helped me understand how textures are stored internally

Comment: Thanks. Good to know it worked out in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you generated the surface with `TTF_Render*_Solid()` or `TTF_Render*_Shaded()`.
However, these functions [return an 8-bit palettized surface](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf.html#SEC42),
which OpenGL does not understand.
This is not detected in your function, where you set the source format (Mode) either to GL_RGB or GL_RGBA, which both are incorrect in that case.

As a solution, make sure to render the text in the blended mode, using one of the `TTF_Render*_Blended()` functions.
These will create a full BGRA surface, which can then be used with `glTexImage2D()`.

Also note that [it is recommended](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Image_precision)
to use a specific internal format with `glTexImage2D()`, so the function call should look like this:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,
  GL_RGBA8,
  img->w, img->h, 0,
  GL_BGRA,
  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img->pixels);
```

Comment: I changed the function to TTF_Render_Blended like you said but now the entire quad is colored in the SDL_Color I specified. I made sure that this is not a shader problem.

Comment: I can think of a couple of causes. Make sure the UV coordinates are correct and indeed map the texture onto the quad. Make sure to sample the right color channels. Last but not least, make sure alpha blending is really enabled. As a simple test, use something like this in the fragment shader: `if (sampledColor.a < 0.5) discard;`. If the text is rendered (without antialiasing), then alpha blending is indeed the problem. Otherwise, it would be useful if you add the full texture loading code, as well as the relevant shader code, to your question, for further review.

Comment: I have added all the function you wanted. The blending should be fine. If there is anything else I should provide please ask immediately. Also I am sorry for the confusion but the color that the quad is colored in is actually not the color I originally had my font in. I was mistaken.